# serilog destructuring - mixed types

Tags: elasticsearch, serilog

I have a class `Response`, where `Data` type is mostly a complex type of SI types like `Voltage`, `Current` etc

```
public class Response
{
   string Name { get; }
   object Data { get; }
   ctor(...) {}

}

public class Voltage {
   double NumberValue { get; }
   ...
}


public class Number {
   bool NumberValue { get; }
   ...
}

public class Text {
   string TextValue { get; }
   ...
}
```

If I destruct it using `{@Response}` and store it in elastic search, these types would explode properly without any clash of types, i.e A `Voltage` would destruct like `Response.Data.NumberValue` (numeric) and a `Text` would destruct to `Response.Data.TextValue` (text).

However, sometimes, it is also possible that `Data` could be just an `int` or a `string`. In those cases it would destruct to `Response.Data` (long) and `Response.Data` (text). Which causes problem in elastic search index.

I am wondering if I can use the `IDestructuringPolicy`s `TryDestructure()` method to custom destruct the `Response` class. I would like the `int` to also destruct to `Response.Data.NumberValue`.

Comment: It seems following could work within `TryDestructure`               `logEventProperties.Add(
                    new LogEventProperty("Data",
                        new StructureValue(new[]
                        {
                            new LogEventProperty("NumberValue", propertyValueFactory.CreatePropertyValue((double)data))
                        })));` Let me test it completely